# Loading Cross Table With Multiple Levels in Flat Format in QlikView

Tags: qlikview

Is it possible to load a cross table in QlikView which has multiple layers in columns and rows? This is an example of a table in Excel which I would like to load as a flat table in QlikView:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Its not trivial in the case of qlikview...BUT..luckly for you I keep a demo file that shows exactly how to accomplish loading multi header tables!
You can download it from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_NIK7vvDnGfRmJnOHpzLWJVTFU/view?usp=sharing).

takes time to understand the logic so study it carefully.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty straightforward using the crosstable function.  Assuming your static data columns (i.e. "Total_CountriesWithAlloc", "Total Countries incl. costs not allocated") are static and constant in number, you can perform a load * from your source to pick up the "new" month columns as they appear over time.

Here's a basic example (just drop the script into a new document and run it to see conceptually how it works).

```
 [Data]:
    CrossTable(Months, Amount, 2)
    LOAD * INLINE [
    StaticDataA,StaticDataB,Jan,Feb,Mar
    AAA,XXX,10,20,30
    BBB,YYY,41,41,41
    CCC,ZZZ,72,82,92
    ];
```

Based on the clarifications, you could try something like this:

[image: Excel Sample]

```
QUALIFY *; 

[Headers]:
LOAD
RecNo() as RecordIndex
,*

FROM [lib://qlikid_graeme.smith/Multi Header.xlsx]
(ooxml, no labels, table is Sheet1)
WHERE RecNo() <4
;



[UnpivotedRawData]:
LOAD
*
FROM [lib://qlikid_graeme.smith/Multi Header.xlsx]
(ooxml, no labels, table is Sheet1)
WHERE RecNo() >=4
;


UNQUALIFY *;

[PivotedData]:
CrossTable(ColRef, Amount, 2)
LOAD 
    *
RESIDENT
    [UnpivotedRawData]
;

DROP TABLE UnpivotedRawData;

RenameMapData:
LOAD 'UnpivotedRawData.A' as FromFieldName, CONCAT([Headers.A]) as ToFieldName Resident Headers;
CONCATENATE LOAD 'UnpivotedRawData.B' as FromFieldName, CONCAT([Headers.B]) as ToFieldName Resident Headers;

RenameMapDataMap:
Mapping Load * Resident RenameMapData;

DROP TABLE RenameMapData;

RENAME FIELDS USING RenameMapDataMap;

ConcatenatedHeaders:
LOAD 'UnpivotedRawData.C' as ColRef, CONCAT([Headers.C]) as ConcatenatedFieldName Resident Headers;
CONCATENATE LOAD 'UnpivotedRawData.D' as ColRef, CONCAT([Headers.D]) as ConcatenatedFieldName Resident Headers;
CONCATENATE LOAD 'UnpivotedRawData.E' as ColRef, CONCAT([Headers.E]) as ConcatenatedFieldName Resident Headers;

DROP TABLE Headers;
```

In this example I have just concatenated the 3 column header rows, but you have the Row ID, so you could easily adapt to split these into new fields if you want.  Also, you should automate the creation of the ConcatenatedHeaders table above by iterating dynamically through the NoOfFields() in the table rather than hard coding it like I have above, particularly if you have a dynamic number of incoming columns.

This is the output in Qliksense (I have done this on QlikSense cloud as I am at home on my mac).  Script should work in Qlikview too though.

[image: Output table in QS]

If you need to split out the individual fields (as per clarified requirements), just replace the last section of the script with this:

```
ConcatenatedHeaders:
LOAD 'UnpivotedRawData.C' as ColRef, CONCAT([Headers.C],'~') as ConcatenatedFieldName  Resident Headers;
CONCATENATE LOAD 'UnpivotedRawData.D' as ColRef, CONCAT([Headers.D],'~') as ConcatenatedFieldName Resident Headers;
CONCATENATE LOAD 'UnpivotedRawData.E' as ColRef, CONCAT([Headers.E],'~') as ConcatenatedFieldName Resident Headers;

DROP TABLE Headers;

JOIN(ConcatenatedHeaders)
LOAD
    ColRef
    ,SubField(ConcatenatedFieldName, '~',1) as Row1Header
    ,SubField(ConcatenatedFieldName, '~',2) as Row2Header
    ,SubField(ConcatenatedFieldName, '~',3) as Row3Header
RESIDENT
    ConcatenatedHeaders;
```

The data should look like this:

[image: Table Browser with Fields Separated]

Comment: but what is with other headers apart from "Month" in the column headers? What is with "RST, ACT..." and with "Year to Date...". 
I know how to import the cross table with crosstable function when the crosstable has only one header in the column headers. That is straightforward. But the million dollar question is: how can I do it when column header has not only one but multiple headers. (btw, it works ok for multiple ROW headers, but I can't fgure out how it functions with multiple column headers.)

Comment: Does each layer in the header (i.e. row) need to be a separate dimension in the ultimate data model, or you just one one value with the full concatenation of the 4 header rows (E.g. December RST Year to Date etc)?

Comment: each layer in the header (i.e. row) needs to be a separate dimension in the ultimate data model (no concatenation).

Comment: Fairly trivial to extract the individual headers to fields using subfield.  Will update example.